# Processing a big xml in parallel using xpath with camel only matches one expression

Tags: xml, apache-camel

Firstly, thanks a lot for your help in advance!

I want to process a big xml file (10MB) in parallel, streaming the ocurrences one by one. The xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PFA date="202002072200" type="daily">
    <CountryList>
       <CountryName code="AARCT" name="Antarctica" IsTerritory="True" />
       <CountryName code="ABKHAZ" name="Abkhazia" IsTerritory="True" />
       ...
    </CountryList>
    <OccupationList>
        <Occupation code="1" name="Occupation 1" />
        <Occupation code="2" name="Occupation 2" />
        ...
    </<OccupationList>
</PFA>
```

There are more grouping tags, but for the sake of simplicity let me reduce it to only two.

I want to send each set of items to different endpoints, and consume them item by item. For the moment, I just wanna log them.

I have tried with the following snippets, but only the first group is shown into the logs for both snippets.

```java
        from("file:/route/to/my/dir")        
            .split(xpath("//PFA/CountryList/CountryName"))
                .streaming().log("Country ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}")
            .split(xpath("//PFA/OccupationList/Occupation"))
                .streaming().log("OccupationList ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}")
```

and also:

```
        from("file:/home/dalonso/Documentos/documentos/normalizador")
            .choice()
                .when(xpath("//PFA/CountryList"))
                    .to("direct:countriesRoute")
                .when(xpath("//PFA/OccupationList"))
                    .to("direct:occupationsRoute");

        from("direct:countriesRoute").split(xpath("//PFA/CountryList/CountryName")).streaming()
                .log("Country ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}").end();

        from("direct:occupationsRoute").split(xpath("//PFA/OccupationList/Occupation")).streaming()
                .log("OccupationList ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}").end();
```

Does anybody have an idea about how to solve it. I suppose it should be something very trivial, but i can't find anything around internet.

Thanks againg for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally achieved it, using the following snippet:

```java
        from("file:/home/dalonso/Documentos/documentos/normalizador")

                .split(xpath("//PFA"))
                .multicast()
                .to("direct:countriesRoute")
                .to("direct:occupationsRoute");

        from("direct:countriesRoute")           
        .split(xpath("//PFA/CountryList/CountryName")).streaming()
                .log("Country ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}").end();

        from("direct:occupationsRoute").split(xpath("//PFA/OccupationList/Occupation")).streaming()
                .log("OccupationList ${headers.CamelSplitIndex} contains: ${body}").end();
```

Please, feel free to make any suggestion in order to improve it. Thanks a lot!!